# How to solve 403 Access Forbidden by CSRFProtector! in Opendocman

Tags: php, wamp

I have been trying to install *OPendocman* for Document management System and I'm facing this problem

```
403 Access Forbidden by CSRFProtector!
```

when I try to login with admin user. Could you help me understanding why?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Change php.ini:
upload_max_filesize = 20M

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I managed to solve it by creating a folder with editing permission in a different location on the example server: "/home2/"yourSite"/public_html/info41/odm_data/" and put this path in the database in the table "odm_settings" field "dataDir" and in functions.php, I added, after,  "$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']" . "/folder where opendocman was installed"

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve this problem with coping CSRFportector.php form older version of opendocman

Answer (score 0):

i experience this on localhost, only when typing address as `http://localhost/opendocman/`, but if you enter the address completely as :

```
http://localhost/opendocman/index.php
```

the message's gone